# Is "understand" always a stative verb?

Tags: grammar

I have read that "understand" is a stative verb and means something like "to know well." However, lately I have had some doubts on whether that is always the case. For example, in the following sentence

"I can't understand what he's saying"

I'm not sure whether "understand" conveys an action or describes a state. If it was being a stative verb in that case, then substituting something like "know" should be possible. However, "I can't know what he's saying" sounds very wrong. In addition, dictionary definitions of "understand" often describe as "perceive; grasp the meaning of" which conflicts with its definition as a stative verb. Also, "comprehend" is often defined as "understand" even though I am fairly sure that is generally a dynamic verb.

Comment: There are 125 000+ Google hits for "suddenly understood".

Comment: But "suddenly knew" is also valid, and "know" is a stative verb.

Comment: 'Suddenly, he knew' shows a punctive transition. ['Punctive verbs describe events which are (nearly) instantaneous'][[Paczynski & Kuperberg_Aspect](http://kuperberglab.nmr.mgh.harvard.edu/publications/posters/Paczynski&Kuperberg_Aspect_Poster_CNS2011.pdf)]. Obviously the knowing (knowledge) then persists, but the transformation is not stative. 'Know' is not just 'a stative verb'; it has senses meaning 'realise' and 'copulate'.

Comment: [Here](http://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/stative-verbs.html) is a list of supposedly *stative* verbs. *Suddenly* seems to work with any of them.

Comment: How does the following sentence sound? _He told me to understand calculus, and eventually I did so._ Be sure to keep the _so_; that's a test for active/stative. Note **He told me to own the house, and eventually I did so*. _Own_ is stative (_rent_ is active, an interesting pair). So if the sentence sounds equally bad, it's stative; if it's OK, it's active. A famous paper by Ross and Lakoff was entitled "A criterion for verb phrase constituency; or, Why you can't _do so into the sink_".

Comment: http://semantics.uchicago.edu/scalarchange/vendler57.pdf

Comment: @John: [*Haj poured water into the bathtub before George could do so into the sink*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=syULAQAAMAAJ&q=%22do+so+into+the+sink%22&dq=%22do+so+into+the+sink%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=anNaVePeHILT7QaBhIHIDA&redir_esc=y). I guess that's all about how ***so*** can be used. Is it another way of saying you can only answer the question *What did you do?* with *I [verb'ed]* using an ***active*** verb?

Comment: FF, read the paper; it's been too long for me to recall. That's just the title, anyway. @jlovegren, Vendler is of course a classic, and "active" is way too simplistic a categorization for serious analysis. However, I try to keep the math and logic to a minimum here on ELU.

Comment: The paper jlovegren linked said that you cannot say something like "to start knowing" doesn't make sense, but I don't see why "to start understanding" can't work. For example, a sentence like "By reading textbooks, we can start understanding physics" doesn't seem invalid.

Comment: I agree that "to start understanding" is a grammatically correct use.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth This is a general query. I know some transformation is associated with verb and some times they are called aspectual verb. But how to know if a verb has such sense of transformation. I am asking from a non native point of view,

Comment: @JohnLawler You can help me here too. Any help is highly appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: 'Suddenly, I understood' means that within a very short space of time (idealistically, an instant) my state of understanding switched from 'don't understand whatever' to 'understand whatever (to some implied level, at least)'. There is a transformation in state. // 'Understand' is normally used statively: 'She understood basic algebra, and found the quadratic's minimum value by completing the square'). Her getting to grips with / mastering basic algebra isn't referred to here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I understand about it, but I am actually thinking about the way you interpreted "KNOW", as having a transitional state. I believe these type of verbs are called inchoative verb. Just want to know how to know what verbs fall under that category of verbs?

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be relying on gut instinct too much.

> You can't know everything, let alone what he's saying.

In English, unlike languages that have methods of indicating and dealing with stative and dynamic verbs, there is little need for distinction.  To complicate things further, English can approximate the "inchoative aspect", which indicates a transition into a state of existence.

> All at once, she understood what her mother had always been saying.

The inchoative often has helping words like "suddenly" to indicate the transition into the state.  This would explain sentences like:

> I can't begin to understand what he's saying about the inchoative aspect.

or more simply:

> I can't understand what he's saying.

Comment: Well, assuming "I can't know what he's saying" is a valid sentence, then the question becomes whether or not "I can't understand what he's saying" means that or is closer in meaning to "I can't comprehend what he's saying." One of the thing that puzzles me is how dictionaries define "understand" and how it conflicts with how it is a stative verb.

Comment: It still acts as a stative verb.  Just because the words to indicate a transition in state aren't there (the "suddenly") doesn't mean that is is how the word is working.  When someone says "I can't understand", they are indicating that they are not able to change state.  Your issue may be more with the word "can" than "understand".  Try experimenting with some other auxiliary verbs and you can see the state-based behavior.

Comment: I can accept that, but one last issue is how most dictionaries define "comprehend" as "to understand" if they work differently and also how their definition for "understand" as "perceive" contrasts with how it's a stative verb. In fact, many dictionaries make it a point to distinguish between the "to grasp the meaning" and "to know" definition. Also, sentences like "I'm not understanding what you're saying" are fairly common.

Comment: Perceive is also a stative verb.  I'm not sure I understand that question.  I agree that the use of the word "grasp" confuses the stative nature of the word; however, I would argue that the phrase "grasp the meaning" is itself a stative construction despite the use of a normally dynamic verb.  This would just be a factor of English's propensity for adopting new meanings for words.